# Can "of all strands" mean of "of all sorts"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, word-choice

Can I use the word "strand" to mean a "sort" of a "kind" of something,
as in:

> Multiple books of all strands have been written on the issue?

If not, what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

One could argue that it would be understood but it may not be accepted since it's not idiomatic.

Other options:

- types
- kinds
- sorts
- flavors
- ilks
- forms
- styles
- varieties

If you want to be more specific, then **be more specific**. Don't just make up a term and expect it to imply what you're trying to say.

> Multiple books with differing opinions, motivations, and ideologies have been written on the issue.

Comment: I mean by strands different opinions, different motivations, and ideologies. i wonder it could be used given that addition.

Comment: @asef There's no inherent meaning of "strands" to imply those things... can you explain why you think it does?

Comment: It sounds to my ear that might be used to convey the notion of things coming from all shores, but I am not sure.

Comment: Perhaps as in "all walks of life"

Comment: What does "strand" have to do with "walks of life"? I'm sorry but it has no **inherent** meaning like what you're trying to force into it and your intention **will not** be conveyed unless you go with something like the more specific option I listed above.

Comment: I just found this: "A single hair, a noodle, even "a line of thought" — any of these things could be called a strand, a long thin length of something."                      http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/strand

Comment: @Catija - One definition of [_strand_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/strand) is: _One of the elements woven together to make an intricate whole, such as the plot of a novel._ It's not hard to imagine that being stretched to a figurative use, e.g., _There are many strands of books in her library._ With that in mind, I think the O.P.'s question is a fair one.

Comment: @J.R. If the point of writing is to be clear, I don't see that use as being easy to understand. I would not understand it that way and I stand by my answer. It is not idiomatic English and many would not understand it, as three of these answers show.

Comment: @Catija - I don't have a problem with your answer to the yes/no question. I was just saying that it's hot hard to imagine why a learner might think this is okay. My comment was more directed at when you said this: _There's no inherent meaning of "strands" to imply those things... can you explain why you think it does?_ I'm just saying that there _is_ a meaning of strand that might make this a viable possibility, at least in the eyes of a learner. That said, I like your suggestion of _ilk_.

Answer (score 1):

The ODO defines the noun *strand* as "An element that forms part of a complex whole." [definition 1.2 of the noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/strand).

This is an extension of the meaning of 1.0: "A single thin length of something such as thread, fiber, or wire, **especially as twisted together with others** [my emphasis]."

So if I go outside and [yank](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/yank) some grass up, I'm likely to end up with not only grass but maybe some weed(s), and/or a flower. So, in a limited manner, I'll have *plants **of all  strands*** in my hand. And although I will also gave *plants **of all types/kinds***, the meaning is not the same.

*Strands* are part of a complex whole (1.2). *Types* and *kinds* do not have this meaning.

Synonyms for *strand* include:

> element, component, factor, ingredient, aspect, feature, strain

There are example sentences with *strand* in the ODO and other dictionaries that you can look at and learn from. After examining these sentences and you feel that your original sentence works, then go for it.

You could perhaps also say something such as:

> Multiple books by authors of all strands (or: every strand) of thought have been written on the issue.

People come from *all strands of life*, and often authors write from *all strands of thought*. In this sense, they are each a part of the complex whole.

And even though *people of all kinds* probably include *people of all strands*, the two terms are not the same. This answer has attempted to show why.

If this is not what you want, you probably want to go with one of the synonyms for types that other answers have listed.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never heard of the expression *of all strands*. You could, however, use *of all kinds* to say what you mean:

> - Multiple books of all kinds...

Or something like this:

> - Multiple books of different types...

Comment: I mean by strands different opinions, different motivations, and ideologies. i wonder it could be used given that addition

Answer (score 0):

"Strand" might be possible here but I don't think it would be usual or the best choice. There are many possible alternatives. "Types" or "kinds" are the ones I would use. There are probably better alternatives. I would also consider changing "multiple" to "many" "a great many" "a huge number" or something similar.